# Merging .less files with identical variables

Tags: less

I am migrating one site into another and need to merge the styles for both sets of templates into a single CSS file (for company workflow reasons). My problem is that both templates use Less files with many identical variable names, so I can't just combine the files to compile.  I'm a novice with Less, so if there is an obvious solution, I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Maybe compile both files and then concatenate both css files in to a single file?

Comment: @muecas Without *maybe*. (There are methods to isolate different templates from each other within single Less session, but why bother when you just concat the resulting CSS and voilà).

Comment: @seven-phases-max haha, i will love to know those methods! :-) They're not documented in the less webste am i right? Or maybe i never been challenged to go for those methods and learn some more.

Comment: @muecas No you don't find it at the docs because it's more about using existing features for different tips and trick (too many tricks to document) rather than a specific syntax invented for a specific task. Basically it's just `& {@import "library1";} & {@import "library2";}` etc. (`&` itself is documented but  various *scope* mechanics it can be used for are not really. Though this is sort of [famous trick](https://github.com/less/less-docs/issues/21)).

Comment: @seven-phases-max i get it, and based on each scope (forced by {}), variables won't be overriden. Thanks for the tip!